# Which sticky notes app you would prefer for iPhone which can synchronized to Google tasks?

Tags: applications, iphone

Which sticky notes app you would prefer for iPhone which can synchronized to Google tasks? I want a simple sticky notes on top and always.

Comment: Do you have some more information on how "a simple sticky notes on top and always." would look? Are you looking for a jailbreak solution where the stick note overlays the normal iOS springboard interface. Or is on top referring to how the app looks only when it's running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by sticky notes, but I have been using the free "GoTasks" for quite some time.  I've found that it is by far the best integration into google tasks, and you can leave little notes with each separate task.